# if my content is not longer than the viewport then i want a div to expand to fill the gap so that a header can be offscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css

If my content is not longer than the viewport then I want a div to expand to fill the gap so that a header can be offscreen I will explain a bit better

I have site x it is a header with a menu then content - all of which scroll - there is a fixed div at the bottom - 25px high so I have added a div to the bottom of my content of 30px - this allows the bottom-most content to be visible when scrolled to the bottom

All pages have a javascript redirect via bookmark to #sectionB - to the menu - so hiding a header banner of about 300px height - on most pages this means content still overflows the viewport - on one or two pages the content is not long enough so the bookmark redirect may only cover 200 or 100px  of the header banner

An obvious fix would be to make the bottom div larger, but this breaks the nice clean effect on the majority of pages

http://www.tpfwales.com/preview/home.html#sectionB  is a page which is longer
http://www.tpfwales.com/preview/info.html#sectionB is a problem page

Is there any way to get javascript to find out the viewport size, compare it to the content size, and if the content size is less than the viewport size - change the value of the div - cbase - at the bottom of the content from 30px to the remanding space plus the height of the header banner

Sorry for being a tiny bit confusing in my description of the problem.

So we have a header, menu, submenu, content, chase - all of which can scroll and then footer which is fixed to the bottom permanently. 
when content from menu down is longer that the viewport then a cbase of 30px is perfect - when the content from menu down is not longer than the viewport I would like cbase to be the height or viewport minus content from menu down. if possible this would adjust when the page adjusts.

Comment: give the div.abs.module a min-height:npx; and display:block or table

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that doesn't seem to help - giving the .module a min height of npx and display block doesn't seem to do anything different and using display of table just seems to cause issues with the layout of some of the sections but does not fix problem